# Calling Fortran from R, Partitioning around medoids

Tags: r, vector, fortran, cluster-analysis, bigdata

Im trying to use the PAM algorithm in the cluster package. My dataset is large, so I keep getting this error when I run the following code

```
#create clusters
pam_fit<- pam(costs, 10, diss =FALSE) #where cost is a datasets with 3 variables, all numeric 

#the error I get is the following 
Error in pam(costs, 10, diss = FALSE) : 
  long vectors (argument 5) are not supported in .Fortran
```

this link seems to suggest that there is a way around it (.call?) but Im not too sure how to do that
http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/LongVectors.html

PS: I know 0 Fortran so if the answer requires running anything in Fortran please be as detailed as possible!!!

thanks.

Comment: The problem is probably because the Fortran code uses 32 bit integers for counting the elements. Seems you will have to rewrite `pam` to use something larger and call it from a different API than `.Fortran`.